# Dependencies solving for GridComponent in @syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, syncfusion, es6-modules

I followed this tutorial http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/getting-started.html

How ever when I run my project, the JIT encounter this error [image: Browser error]

The InteliSense also show the same error [image: IntelliSense error]

I set up the `SyncFusionModule` as Angular Module to export all "Syncfusion EJ 2 for Angular" components I'm planning to use in the `BenchmarkModule`. The `GridComponent` in 
`@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids/src/grid/index` can be picked up by Angular; therefore, it is recognized as an Angular component. However, the `datasouce` is not declared in 'GridComponent' but in its parent `Grid` which is not Angular component but a standard one declared in `@syncfusion\ej2-grids`. It seems like I missed an dependencies import somewhere to help Angular find the definition for `Grid`. But I wasn't sure how to resolve this issue.

At first, I thought it's due to the fact that I skipped the SystemJS mapping which described in http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/getting-started.html#configuring-system-js; therefore, I raised this question [Webpack solution for SystemJS mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579779/webpack-solution-for-systemjs-mapping). But one of the answers suggested me it may not the reason.

Here is the GitHub repo https://github.com/lamLeX/IocPerformance/tree/gh-pages/IocPerformanceResultWebApp/src/app in case one would like to know how the files are structured to help me with the dependencies resolving because I don't have much experience in JS dependencies resolving; especially ES6 modules resolve.

Update from the answer:
The trouble code is taken from this example http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/grid/grouping and I have notified SyncFusion team about the bug in sample code.

```
<div class="control-section">
<ej-grid height="320" [datasource]="data" [groupsettings]="groupOptions" [allowgrouping]="true" allowsorting="true" allowpaging="true">
    <e-columns>
        <e-column field="Inventor" width="180" headertext="Inventor Name"></e-column>
        <e-column field="NumberofPatentFamilies" width="220" textalign="right" headertext="Number of Patent Families"></e-column>
        <e-column field="Country" width="140" headertext="Country"></e-column>
        <e-column field="Active" width="120"></e-column>
        <e-column field="Mainfieldsofinvention" width="200" headertext="Main fields of invention"></e-column>
    </e-columns>
</ej-grid>
<div style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: right">Source:
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prolific_inventors" target="_blank">Wikipedia: List of Prolific inventors</a>
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Here GridModule isn't `import`ed in module, https://github.com/lamLeX/IocPerformance/blob/gh-pages/IocPerformanceResultWebApp/src/app/sync-fusion/sync-fusion.module.ts . I guess that's the problem. For non-Angular components there may be other options, but for Angular components this error occurs when a component declaration is missing.

Comment: I tried to add import { Grid } from '@syncfusion/ej2-grids'; before posting the question but still got the error

Comment: and adding Grid to import array in `@NgModule` only generates another error saying `Unexpected value 'Grid' imported by the module 'SyncFusionModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

Comment: Yes, compiler does debugging for you. It should be `import { GridModule } from '@syncfusion/ej2-grids'` and `imports: [GridModule]`. This should work for you.

Comment: There is no `GridModule` in `@syncfusion/ej2-grids`. `Grid` is in `@syncfusion/ej2-grids` and `GridComponent` is in `@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids`. `GridModule` is an Angular Module that declares and export `GridComponent` in its `declarations` and `exports` array. I tried to import Grid in my `SyncFusionModule` using ` import { Grid } from '@syncfusion/ej2-grids';` as you suggested but JIT still fail to find the Grid's properties

Comment: I'm not sure why you decided to import @syncfusion/ej2-grids in the first place. It's used internally by  @syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids. There's no need to touch it in Angular app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is be `ej2-ng-grids`, not `ej2-grids`, and [`GridModule` is right there](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids/blob/master/src/index.ts). So it should be

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { GridModule, GridComponent, PageService, SortService, FilterService, GroupService } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids';

@NgModule({
  imports: [GridModule],
  exports: [GridModule],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [PageService, SortService, FilterService, GroupService]
})
export class SyncFusionModule { }
```

And there is no need to do that because this is already done in [`GridAllModule`](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids/blob/master/src/grid/grid-all.module.ts). It should be imported in application module instead of custom `SyncFusionModule`.

Additionally, code above contains wrong inputs - `datasource`, etc.`They should be`dataSource` and so on, [according to the documentation](http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/api-gridComponent.html).

Comment: Did you suggestion is exactly what I had done here https://github.com/lamLeX/IocPerformance/blob/gh-pages/IocPerformanceResultWebApp/src/app/sync-fusion/sync-fusion.module.ts Did you try to call ng serve and try it locally on your machine?

Comment: I also tried to replace all import statement in `SyncFusionModule` and replace them with `GridAllModule`. Still got the same error.

Comment: You don't need a thing like SyncFusionModule at all when you use GridAllModule. You likely continue to receive this error because it is [`dataSource`](http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/api-gridComponent.html), not `datasource` - so does `groupsettings`, etc. Fortunately, Angular can detect these typos.

Comment: It works. I'm aware that js is case-sensitive but I didn't know that it's applicable to httml binding :D. The reason I opted to have `SyncFusionModule` is because later on I'm planning exporting @syncfusion/ej2-ng-charts

Comment: Could you please update your answer to add the resolution about the dataSource? Thank you very much for your time on this case.

Comment: You're welcome. Sure. I would suggest to add troubled code pieces to the question, link-only questions are difficult to follow and can be spoiled when links break.